# Type is changing in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Can anybody explain how does it happen and why?
Is it a bug or I missed something?

```
function isString<T>(arg:T):boolean {
     return (typeof(arg)==='string')?true:false;
}

let myEcho;
myEcho = isString;
let myInt :number = 5;
console.log(myInt  + ", Type is "+ typeof(myInt)) // 5, Type is number
myInt = myEcho("hi");
console.log(myInt  + ", Type is "+ typeof(myInt)) //  true, Type is boolean
```

I defined myInt as a number, but it changed to boolean!!!

Comment: You defined it _first_ as a number by assigning 5 (a number) to it, but then you reassigned a boolean value (the result of `myEcho("hi")`) to the same variable (`myInt`), overwriting the initial value (5).

Comment: @AlexSzabó In TypeScript we can not change the type of a variable but here it changes. The problem is why does it change?

Comment: My guess is that `myEcho` is of type `any` (because it's declared without a type &  it fails to infer the type of function `isString` - more specifically I think it fails to infer the types in the signature of that function), so it won't complain.

Answer (score 2):

I pinged [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) on Twitter about this because you were saying there definitely wasn't an error, but I couldn't imagine a setting that would affect this. There is one!

You appear to have `noImplicitAny` disabled. When you have that disabled, TypeScript doesn't try as hard to refine the types of variables that implicitly have the `any` type, such as your `myEcho`. So TypeScript doesn't know what `myEcho("hi")` returns and lets the assignment to your `myInt` variable go unreported. [Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgZSgJxmA5gHgBUA+ACgENNcAuQgSmoCM44AbAU3KQG8AoRAQMzsoITElJQAngAd2cYBSp0AvGoDkKLDlzq6Afiwh21YOVYp2Abl4BfXrw5REAWykBRCAAs4Nt559EFWR0bTwbJ1cpAEkwZ2owEBdGdkwgxABWGwgEFDZ2ADpWOFxSN1jnRABqRAAiABpEQll2ELqa6TkFMpi4ujpEAHpBzMbmuTbE5NTecrj0-284UlqvGFq6bNz8opKeioEahqaWttqOlu65qH6hkcQjdjHT1ERmfK4gA) on the TypeScript playground with `noImplicitAny` disabled.

With `noImplicitAny` enabled (best practice), that code produces an error from the TypeScript compiler on the `myInt = myEcho("hi");` statement:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.

[Live copy showing the error here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgZSgJxmA5gHgBUA%20ACgENNcAuQgSmoCM44AbAU3KQG8AoRAQMzsoITElJQAngAd2cYBSp0AvGoDkKLDlzq6Afiwh21YOVYp2Abl4BfXrw5REAWykBRCAAs4Nt559EFWR0bTwbJ1cpAEkwZ2owEBdGdkwgxABWGwgEFDZ2ADpWOFxSN1jnRABqRAAiABpEQll2ELqa6TkFMpi4ujpEAHpBzMbmuTbE5NTecrj0-284UlqvGFq6bNz8opKeioEahqaWttqOlu65qH6hkcQjdjHT1ERmfK4gA)

But even when there's an error, the default behavior of the TypeScript compiler is to still produce the JavaScript output (if it can, and it can in this case). So at **runtime** you see the behavior you've described, because `myInt` does contain a `boolean` (from `myEcho`), not a `number`, and you're using JavaScript's runtime `typeof` operator.

Watch for errors from the TypeScript compiler. That's where you'll find type errors like this one.

You can also tell TypeScript *not* to output JavaScript when there's an error using the `--noEmitOnError` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: I have tried on another system with TS version 3.7.5 and without error it is working.

Comment: @HesamA - Well, presumably you're using the same `tsconfig.json` or similar. As I said above, what matters is having `noImplicitAny` disabled. What system you run the code on seems irrelevant.